# Schema describes boolean, string found instead when I create list through Mailchimp API

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, checkbox, mailchimp

I'm new at developing Mailchimp application.
and I'm trying to create list through Mailchimp API.
anyone has same issue with this error?

Here is my HTML code for checkbox input:

```html
<input id="email_type_option" type="checkbox" name="email_type_option" value="true">
<input id="email_type_optionHidden" type="hidden" name="email_type_option" value="false">
```

and here is the script to save function:
I used this conditional:

```js
if (document.getElementById('email_type_option').checked) {
    document.getElementById('email_type_optionHidden').disabled = true;
} else if(document.getElementById('email_type_option')) {
    document.getElementById('email_type_optionHidden').disabled = false;
}
```

and the response from API is:

```
"{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/…/mai…/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Invalid Resource","status":400,"detail":"The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.","instance":"","errors":[{"field":"email_type_option","message":"Schema describes boolean, string found instead"}]}"
```

I tried to put boolean value at my checkbox input but it always return to that error.

if I console.log this on browser it shows right to boolean value but I don't know why still got that error when I send it.

I want to make this value return into boolean not a string like the error says.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got to solve this problem. I used ajax to send it to the server or controller (I used Laravel PHP framework) and actually what I sent was converted to string (include number or boolean) because I used json_encode when I want to send it through Mailchimp API. 
So I used [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function in PHP to keep my boolean value not to be converted as string.

Here is my ajax request:

```
save = function()
    {
        // if checkbox is checked send true, if not checked send false.
        if (document.getElementById('email_type_option').checked) {
            document.getElementById('email_type_optionHidden').disabled = true;
        } else if(document.getElementById('email_type_option')) {
            document.getElementById('email_type_optionHidden').disabled = false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: $('#form').attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(xhr)
            {
                var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
                if (token){
                    return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CRSF-TOKEN', token);
                }
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data.status !== 'true') {
                    swal("Error!", "Details: "+data.message+" .", "error");
                } else if (data.status == 'true') {
                    $('#modal').modal('hide');
                    swal("Success", "Your mailchimp list has been created. Go configure your form!", "success");
                    formSetting();
                    // console.log(data); // test purpose only
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                swal("Error!", "Error creating mailchimp list. "+ errorThrown +".", "error");
            }
        });
    }
```

So here is my input request to controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{       

    $url = 'https://' . $this->dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/';

    $reqs = json_encode([

    'name' => $request->name,
    'permission_reminder' => $request->permission_reminder,
    'email_type_option' => $request->email_type_option = filter_var($request->email_type_option, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN), // to make it boolean
    'contact' => $request->contact,
    // $request->contact[company],
    // $request->contact[address1],
    // $request->contact[city],
    // $request->contact[state],
    // $request->contact[zip],
    // $request->contact[country],
    'campaign_defaults' => $request->campaign_defaults
    // $request->campaign_defaults[from_name],
    // $request->campaign_defaults[from_email],
    // $request->campaign_defaults[subject],
    // $request->campaign_defaults[language]
    ]);


    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $this->apiKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); // if we use custom method (e.g: PUT/PATCH or DELETE)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $reqs);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = json_decode($response, true);

    // Validation if get error
    if ( !empty($result['status']) ) {
        if ($result['status'] == 400) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'false',
                'message' => $result['errors'][0]['message']
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        // Creating forms table
        $form = DB::table('forms')->insertGetId(
            [
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'nama' => 'Untitled',
                'description' => 'Describe your form here',
                'button_name' => 'Submit',
                'listID_mailchimp' => $result['id'], // get ID from response cURL
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ]
        );
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'true'
        ]);
    }

}
```

See? the 'email_type_option' is filtered to boolean. and it works for me. Thank you.